# How to get Adventures on an Oxy-core run?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I don't have any of the Items of the Month nor do I plan on donating for Mr. Accessories to buy any of the yearly familiars. How do I generate Adventures if I can't eat or drink? While I would normally buy any of these spleen items in a normal run (or buy them beforehand and pull them from Hagnk's), I can't do this in a Hardcore run. How do I generate turns in a Hardcore Oxygenarian run so I don't take twelve years to finish it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [KoL wiki](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Hardcore_Oxygenarian_Strategy) has massive amounts of information on this.  Get a [Dead Guy's watch](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Dead_guys_watch).  Make a [Meat Maid](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Meat_maid).  If you are a Seal Clubber, or have permed it, used [pulverize](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Pulverize) to get Twinkly wads.

(It'll still take forever, though.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [Crimbco Handbook Ch 1](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/CRIMBCO_Employee_Handbook_%28chapter_1%29) which gives 1 more adventure at Rollover. It is 375k in the mall right now. It only gives 1 adv, but I assume that is important in Oxycore. As Steven Burnap said, [pulverize](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Pulverize) is also going to be very useful, since spleen will be a major source of adventures, and you have no spleen fams.